# MySQL user var not incrementing

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is working perfectly in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffcba/22 but when I attempt it on my production server, it does not work in the sense that the @row_number does not increment when @user = user which ends up with these following results:

```
+------+-------+-----+---------+
| user | file  | log | billing |
+------+-------+-----+---------+
|    1 | b.pdf |   3 |       1 |
|    1 | b.pdf |   3 |       1 |
|    1 | a.pdf |   2 |       0 |
|    2 | d.pdf |   2 |       1 |
|    2 | d.pdf |   2 |       1 |
|    2 | c.pdf |   1 |       0 |
|    3 | f.pdf |   3 |       0 |
|    3 | e.pdf |   1 |       0 |
|    4 | g.pdf |   0 |       1 |
|    4 | i.pdf |   2 |       1 |
|    4 | g.pdf |   0 |       1 |
|    4 | j.pdf |   3 |       0 |
|    4 | i.pdf |   2 |       1 |
|    4 | h.pdf |   1 |       0 |
+------+-------+-----+---------+
```

...as opposed to the 4 row result that the fiddle boils down to, which is what it SHOULD be. The fiddle was a test and although my production variables differed slightly, I ended up copying the schema from the fiddle to build test tables to confirm that everything, as far as I know, is exactly the same. I'm currently running MySQL 5.6.23 while the fiddle is utilizing 5.6 as referenced in the dropdown.

It seems to be running correctly on fiddle with the following settings:

**Schema:**

```
create table tests ( ID int, user int, log int);
insert into tests values 
(  1,     1,    2), 
(  2,     1,    2), 
(  3,     2,    2), 
(  4,     3,    2), 
(  5,     3,    2), 
(  6,     4,    2); 

create table files (ID int, file varchar(10),  log int, billing int, user int);
insert into files values
(  1,  'a.pdf',    2,        0,     1), 
(  2,  'b.pdf',    3,        1,     1), 
(  3,  'c.pdf',    1,        0,     2), 
(  4,  'd.pdf',    2,        1,     2), 
(  5,  'e.pdf',    1,        0,     3), 
(  6,  'f.pdf',    3,        0,     3), 
(  7,  'g.pdf',    0,        1,     4), 
(  8,  'h.pdf',    1,        0,     4), 
(  9,  'i.pdf',    2,        1,     4), 
( 10,  'j.pdf',    3,        0,     4)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT user, file, log, billing
FROM (
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @user=user THEN @row_number+1 
                         ELSE 1 
                    END AS row_number,
       @user:=user AS user,
       file, log, billing
FROM (        
SELECT 1 AS pri, t.user, f.file, f.log, f.billing
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user, log
      FROM tests 
      WHERE log = 2) AS t
INNER JOIN files AS f 
ON (t.user = f.user AND t.log = f.log AND f.billing = 1)   

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 AS pri, t.user, f.file, f.log, f.billing
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user, log
      FROM tests 
      WHERE log = 2) AS t
INNER JOIN files AS f 
ON (t.user = f.user AND f.billing = 1)   
WHERE f.log > t.log OR f.log = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 3 AS pri, t.user, f.file, f.log, f.billing       
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user, log
      FROM tests 
      WHERE log = 2) AS t
INNER JOIN files AS f ON (t.user = f.user)  
ORDER BY user, pri, log DESC ) s ) r
WHERE r.row_number = 1
ORDER BY user
```

**Results as desired from fiddle**

```
+------+-------+-----+---------+
| user | file  | log | billing |
+------+-------+-----+---------+
|    1 | b.pdf |   3 |       1 |
|    2 | d.pdf |   2 |       1 |
|    3 | f.pdf |   3 |       0 |
|    4 | i.pdf |   2 |       1 |
+------+-------+-----+---------+
```

If anyone knows any reason why this might not work, perhaps a setting or whatever, any insight in to correcting it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: You are reading and updating the same variable in the same select statement - that's going to give inconsistent results - there is no guarantee that `@user = user` will be evaluated before, or after, `@user := user`

Comment: As a general rule, you should post your code in the actual SO question.  Nothing wrong with a fiddle though.

Comment: @pala_ yeah I was intending to evaluate per row - is there a more solid approach to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL results are indeterminate when you try and read a variable in the same select as you modify it.

[5.6 User Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html)

> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:
>
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...; However, the order of evaluation for
>   expressions involving user variables is undefined.

To get around this, we can force the order of execution by using nested conditional statements. What you should try doing is changing your `case` statement, to a nested `if` statement.

So change this:

```
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @user=user THEN @row_number+1   -- do i happen first?
                         ELSE 1 
                    END AS row_number,
       @user:=user AS user,                                   -- or do i?
```

Which is where may be running into trouble - we dont know if the `case` or the `@user := user` will be evaluated first, to this:

```
select if(@user = user,                        -- if we are processing the same user
          @row_number := @row_number + 1,      -- increment row number
          if(@user := user,                    -- otherwise set current user
             @row_number := 1,                 -- then set row number to 1
             @row_number := 1)) as row_number, -- failsafe if user is null
       user,
       file, log, billing
```

And the chain of `ifs` will ensure your variables contain the values you expect, when you expect them.

I have modified your fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffcba/28) and you can see the results are the same as what they were previously, but they should be a little bit more reliable.  Please try it out on your other data and see how it goes.

Also, the variables aren't being initialised, which is something that needs to happen. You can either do that by explicitly setting them in statements before the query, or you can `cross join` to a simple select that sets them - i tend to prefer the latter.

`cross join (select @row_number := 1, @user := 0) q`

[fiddle updated once again](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffcba/33)

Comment: Thanks so much @pala_, I would love to say it's working now but still not unfortunately. I'm still getting the same 14 rows as before. Actually, in the fiddle I see 14 rows also

Comment: i removed the `where` clause in the fiddle - is the goal to get the most recent bill per user?

Comment: Oh ok, I see. But still nothing on my machine - each of the row_numbers is '1'

Comment: if you run that fiddle schema and query on your local database, what results do you get?

Comment: the 14 rows, each with 'row_number' being '1' - I copied over the schema and the query to test and reproduce the same situation that the fiddle is working with - I'd paste the results here but I don't think they'd be formatted

Comment: that's definitely weird - are the results ordered the way you expect? ie by user, pri, log?

Comment: Here's the link to the snap from my phpmyadmin: http://i61.tinypic.com/2quuqs5.jpg - just to show what's going on - yeah, order seems perfectly fine

Comment: ugh. forgot something basic - the variables need to be initialised first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77473/discussion-between-pala-and-jbarnes).